# Using purrr modify2 to modify a vector, based on elements of two vectors

Tags: r, arrays, tidyverse, purrr

I'm attempting to modify values in a vector, based on two conditions using two different vectors and `purrr::modify2`, haven't quite got the syntax correct and can't find examples on web.  Here is mwe:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
arr1 <- c(6, 2, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 2, 3, 7)
arr2 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
prob <- c(0.65, 0.45)

arr1 %<>% modify2(arr1,
                  arr2,
                  ~ if (.x == 2 & .y == 0) ~ rbinom(1,1,prob[1]) * 2
                  else
                       if (.x == 2 & .y != 0) ~ rbinom(1,1,prob[2]) * 2)
```

I'm trying to get it to find when `.x == 2` and `.y == 0` (same index in both arrays), then replace the 2 in .x with the value generated by `rbinom(1,1,prob[1]) * 2`, which I think should be either 0 or 2? Then if `.x == 2` and `.y != 0`, use a different probability to replace the value in `arr1`.  I also want the rbinom calculation done individually for each entry, if that makes sense?  Do I need to use `function (x) ......`   notation to make it evaluates for each instance? Obviously simpler and/or more elegant solutions most welcome. Thx. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution is to use `case_when`:

```
arr1 <- modify2(arr1, arr2, ~dplyr::case_when(
  .x == 2 && .y == 0 ~ rbinom(1,1,prob[1]) * 2,
  .x == 2 && .y != 0 ~ rbinom(1,1,prob[2]) * 2,
  TRUE ~ .x ))
```

Note that you don't need `%<>%`; you are already passing `arr1` as the first argument, so you can simply assign the result back with the standard `<-`.

Comment: Thanks Artem, yes my mistake, will correct, and also for the solution. J